# Copy value from select to text

Tags: jquery

I want to copy a select's value to text field when even the select's value changes.
My code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#select').change(function() {
      $('#text').val($('#select').val());
   });  
});
```

This code works only when I change the select's value using the mouse, but if I focus it and press the up/down arrow key it does not work.

Comment: Changing it with the keyboard will still fire the event, but it doesn't fire until the element loses focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior, the actual value isn't changed until an option is selected. It should still work when you press "enter" after making a selection with the up/down arrows.

You try and can bind more events if you want, example:

```
$('#select').bind('change click keyup', function() {
  $('#text').val($(this).val());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2G9F/

Answer (score 3):

You could try this [jQuery Watch Plugin](http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/) in addition to your `.change` handler? Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select').change(onChange);
    $("#select").watch('value', onChange);

    function onChange(){
      $('#text').val($('#select').val());
    }
});
```

And you'll have to include that plugin on your page of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( '#select' ).keydown( function( )
{
    ...
} );
```

or

```
$( '#select' ).keyup( function( )
{
    ...
} );
```

depending on your needs should work.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$('#select').bind('change keypress click', function)
```